# Batch file freezes on pause command

Tags: batch-file, freeze

If I create a batch file, and double click it to execute, it freezes at any pause command, and does not give the option to "press any key".
If I run it from a command prompt it works fine.
Used to work fine.

Any thoughts?

Comment: no way to tell without seeing your code.

Answer (score 0):

Since I can not see your code, I am having to make some assumptions. One possible reason is because you are using `pause> nul` which suppresses the output.